# Non-interactive apt upgrade

Tags: bash, vagrant, apt

I'm trying to provision a machine using Vagrant and plain bash scripts.

The two lines are:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -yq
```

However, it doesn't work as expected:

```
default: Configuration file '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades'
default:  ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
default:  ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
default:    What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
default:     Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
default:     N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
default:       D     : show the differences between the versions
default:       Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
default:  The default action is to keep your current version.
default: 
default: *** release-upgrades (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
default: 
default:  end of file on stdin at conffile prompt
```

Is there any other option I could use to provide a `Y` answer to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### < Apt 1.1

Try the following command to force upgrade for non-interactive sessions:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
        apt-get \
                -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" \
                --force-yes \
                -fuy \
                dist-upgrade
```

<sup>Note: Use `--force-confold` to keep old, and `--force-confnew` to keep new configs.</sup>

Source: [apt-get -y upgrade for non-interactive sessions - and replacing conf files in /etc](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-devel@lists.debian.org/msg249363.html).

#### >= Apt 1.1

If you're using Apt 1.1 or above, [`--force-yes` has been deprecated](https://tracker.mender.io/browse/CFE-2360), so you've to use the options starting with `--allow` instead, e.g. `--allow-downgrades`, `--allow-remove-essential`, `--allow-change-held-packages`.

So the command is:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  apt-get \
  -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold \
  -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef \
  -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages
```

Source: [CFE-2360: Make apt_get package module version aware](https://github.com/cfengine/masterfiles/commit/f522dcd54482dffd99ccd690805a97f92216c0e6).

Related:

- [100% non-interactive Debian dist-upgrade](https://serverfault.com/q/48724/130437)
- [apt-get update non interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33370297/55075)
- [How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?](https://serverfault.com/q/227190/130437)

Comment: The command as shown, on apt 2.4.10 (ubuntu 22.04) gives an Usage error, I guess because there is no apt-get subcommand? So we should do the above once with "update", and then again the same but with "upgrade" ?