# Packer VM creation in Azure hangs while configuring openssh-server

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, azure, packer, azure-devops

While creating a Ubuntu VM in Azure with Packer, the installation process stops and hangs while configuring `openssh-server`. The command line prompts for you to select an option, and since this is an automatic build it just hangs until the process times out. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
    azure-arm.ubuntu: Configuring openssh-server
    azure-arm.ubuntu: --------------------------
    azure-arm.ubuntu:
    azure-arm.ubuntu: A new version (/tmp/fileu2AVnQ) of configuration file /etc/ssh/sshd_config is
    azure-arm.ubuntu: available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.
    azure-arm.ubuntu:
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   1. install the package maintainer's version
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   2. keep the local version currently installed
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   3. show the differences between the versions
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   4. show a side-by-side difference between the versions
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   5. show a 3-way difference between available versions
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   6. do a 3-way merge between available versions
    azure-arm.ubuntu:   7. start a new shell to examine the situation
    azure-arm.ubuntu:
    azure-arm.ubuntu: What do you want to do about modified configuration file sshd_config?
```

Comment: What command are you running to configure?

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to be getting generated by the apt/apt-get update of the application as you are upgrading an instance of openssh server.

Looking at This post: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-devel@lists.debian.org/msg249363.html

It would appear that the answer is to use something similar tot he below:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
        apt-get \
                -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" \
                --force-yes \
                -fuy \
                dist-upgrade
```

Alteratively, this post: [automatic yes's to linux update/upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1638779/automatic-yess-to-linux-update-upgrade)
Suggests trying:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq upgrade
```