# Cannot force noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade on CIS Ubuntu 22.04 LTS instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, ubuntu-22.04

I've a CIS Ubuntu 22.04 LTS base image from AWS, which I'm attempting to use Packer to burn myself a base image from.

As this is a fully non-interactive pipeline, I cannot have any tty issues and the build is failing.  I've researched this for a long time now, and I'm out of ideas:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get \
  -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold \
  -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef \
  -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential \
  --allow-change-held-packages dist-upgrade
```

should work but still dumps me at the same menu found [in this question](https://superuser.com/q/1638779/383892).

The only suspicions I have at the moment are

- /tmp is noexec which might affect libc6 updates - but this shouldn't result in the problem experienced
- Some other CIS-related preparation may have been applied to the source marketplace image which I'm not aware of.

What can I do to force this machine to dist-upgrade non-interactively with the old/default configs of files encountered?

I note this on attempt:

```
Can't exec "/tmp/libc6.config.uLjYjf": Permission denied at /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/perl-base/IPC/Open3.pm line 178.
```

which I cannot do much about.

I also found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444094/how-to-do-apt-get-dist-upgrade-with-noninteractive) but when I run

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "grub-efi grub-efi/install_devices multiselect /dev/sda1"
debconf-set-selections <<< "kdump-tools kdump-tools/install_kdump boolean true"
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -y dist-upgrade
```

I still get the menu up.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `sudo` sanitizes the environment of the command it runs. So instead of `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get ...`, try `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get ...`.