# How to skip the password typing when installing library

Tags: linux, docker, apt-get, ldap

I installed the library with.

```
$sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```

While installing it stops and asks,

```
please enter the password for the admin entry in your ldap directory.
```

I am using Dockerfile, so I want to skip this procedure.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-interactive apt upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1412054/non-interactive-apt-upgrade)

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/18429/how-to-quietly-install-ldap-on-ubuntu-client etc.

Comment: Thank you I read the articles and solved I update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I do like this in `dockerfile`

```
RUN echo 'slapd/root_password password password' | debconf-set-selections &&\
    echo 'slapd/root_password_again password password' | debconf-set-selections && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils

#RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libmysqlclient-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev libjpeg8-dev liblcms2-dev libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3-dev python2.7-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev 

RUN echo "slapd slapd/no_configuration boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd slapd/domain string ldaptest.local" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd shared/organization string 'LDAP Test'" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd slapd/password1 password root_password" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd slapd/password2 password root_password" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "jslapd slapd/backend select HDB" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd slapd/purge_database boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd slapd/allow_ldap_v2 boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "slapd slapd/move_old_database boolean true" | debconf-set-selections

RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive slapd

RUN apt-get install ldap-utils slapd -y

#RUN apt-get install slapd -qq

RUN apt-get install ldap-utils tox lcov valgrind -y
```